# Integrating Line Style into MA/EMA Trend Line

Tags: function, styles, line, pine-script, trend

Wondering if I could get a little help integrating a line style into an MA/EMA script. The top portion is a direct pull from tradingviews help section on how to style a trend line.

```
//@version=4
study(title="Set line style with input", overlay=true)

// STEP 1. Make the input with pull-down menu
styleOption = input(title="Line Style", type=input.string, 
     options=["solid (─)", "dotted (┈)", "dashed (╌)", 
     "arrow left (←)", "arrow right (→)", "arrows both (↔)"], 
     defval="solid (─)")

// STEP 2. Convert the input to a proper line style value
lineStyle = styleOption == "dotted (┈)" ? line.style_dotted :
     styleOption == "dashed (╌)" ? line.style_dashed :
     styleOption == "arrow left (←)" ? line.style_arrow_left :
     styleOption == "arrow right (→)" ? line.style_arrow_right :
     styleOption == "arrows both (↔)" ? line.style_arrow_both :
         line.style_solid

// STEP 3. Use the input option to set the line's style
if barstate.islastconfirmedhistory
    // Create a new line and immediately set its style
    line.new(x1=bar_index[55], y1=close[55],
         x2=bar_index, y2=close, width=4, color=color.blue,
         style=lineStyle)
    
    // Or make a line, and then change its style
    myLine = line.new(x1=bar_index[35], y1=close[35],
         x2=bar_index, y2=close, width=4, color=color.orange)
    
    line.set_style(id=myLine, style=lineStyle)


// EMA Example Need to Integreate Above style    
len1 = input(21, minval=1, title="EMA 1")
src1 = input(close, title="EMA 1 source")
plot(ema(src1, len1), color=#8b0000, title="EMA 1",linewidth=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can not use the below with plot funtion. The below can be used with line, hline function to draw horizontal and vertical lines.

```
styleOption = input(title="Line Style", type=input.string, 
     options=["solid (─)", "dotted (┈)", "dashed (╌)", 
     "arrow left (←)", "arrow right (→)", "arrows both (↔)"], 
     defval="solid (─)")

// STEP 2. Convert the input to a proper line style value
lineStyle = styleOption == "dotted (┈)" ? line.style_dotted :
     styleOption == "dashed (╌)" ? line.style_dashed :
     styleOption == "arrow left (←)" ? line.style_arrow_left :
     styleOption == "arrow right (→)" ? line.style_arrow_right :
     styleOption == "arrows both (↔)" ? line.style_arrow_both :
         line.style_solid
```